# All in one banner---link images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I bought code for image presentation and I was wondering if and how I can put a link on the images...
example:

http://orhsfoundation.com/Trial

bought it from here:

http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-banner-rotator-content-slider-carousel/full_screen_preview/1534434 (it's Banner with playlist)

also less importantly I have this annoying move cursor on the images. the is nothing in the css that tell it to do that.

Comment: Adding cursor:default to the style for the images will get rid of the move cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this in your css in the div containing the image. If you remove the css shown below from this element it will correct the cursor.

It doesnt have an id, but it has these classes (`allinone_bannerWithPlaylist easy ui-draggable`)

```
cursor: url(http://orhsfoundation.com/skins/hand.cur), url(http://orhsfoundation.com/skins/hand.cur), move;
```

You can also overwrite this by putting `cursor:default` on the image.

Also to put a link on an image you need to use the `a` tag

```
<a href="LINKTOPAGE.html2"><img src="LINKTOIMAGE" /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks the cursor is fixed! however, putting an ancor tag on the image doesn't work for me...is there something i need to do on the javascript side?

Comment: No problem @user1533928. You can accept my answer by clicking the tick to the left. I would greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: @user1533928 There isnt, are you sure your putting the anchor tag around the image? Like this <a><img /></a>?

Comment: Yes I did 
<a href="about.html"><img src="Assets/Images/01_easyPlaylist.jpg" alt=""  data-title="Lorem Ipsum Dolor1" data-text-id="#allinone_bannerWithPlaylist_photoText1" data-desc="Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque hendrerit " border="0" /></a>

Comment: If i try your code on jsfiddle it works (apart from the image not loading). Maybe you should make a new question asking why the image is not a link? -> http://jsfiddle.net/Z2ka5/

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'data-link' into the `<li>` around the image:

`<li data-transition="fade" data-target="_self" data-link="http://www.com"><img width="580" height="358" border="0" alt="" src="image.jpg" /></li>`